# Conditional Scrolling view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nsnotificationcenter

I have TextField1 and TextField2
I would like to scroll a scrolling View only when Keyboard is shown due to TextField2.
This is my actual code.
Is there any solution?

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {    
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

-(void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *) notification {
   self.ScrollView.center = CGPointMake(self.originalCenter.x,
                                        self.originalCenter.y-100);
}

-(void) keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *) notification {   
    self.ScrollView.center = CGPointMake(self.originalCenter.x,
                                         self.originalCenter.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to listen for the `UITextfield` delegate methods:

```
textfield2.delegate = self;

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField*)textField {
    if (textField == textField2) {
        //ENABLE THE SCROLLING
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField*)textField {
    if (textField == textField2) {
        //DISABLE THE SCROLLING
    }
}
```

Just customize the methods to your needs.

If it needs to be exactly when the keyboard shows, you can have a bool to check:

```
if (textField == textField2) {
    scrollBool = YES;
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField*)textField {
    if (textField == textField2) {
        scrollBool = NO;
    }
}

-(void)keyBoardDidShow.... {
    if (scrollBool) {
        // do the scrolling
    }
}
```